# Covariance inequality and strong mixing

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, self-learning

In this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3375951/strong-mixing-coefficient-of-davydovs-inequality) I conclude that, for a error process $\{\epsilon_t\}$, $\mid Cov(\epsilon_t,\epsilon_l)\mid \leq C \alpha(\mid t-l \mid)^{1/p}$, for some constant $C$ (given conditions on the boundeness of integrals).
Now, my question is why the following statement is true:

Let$\{\epsilon_t\}$ be $\alpha$-mixing (or strongly mixing). If $\mid t-k\mid>M$ for $k\in\{a,b,c\}$, then $\mid Cov(\epsilon_t,\epsilon_a\epsilon_b\epsilon_c)\mid\leq C'\alpha(M)^{1/p}$ for some constant $C'$?

I don't know if there always exists an $k\in\{a,b,c\}:\mid Cov(\epsilon_t,\epsilon_a\epsilon_b\epsilon_c)\mid\leq \mid Cov(\epsilon_t,\epsilon_k)\mid$, because then I could use $\mid Cov(\epsilon_t,\epsilon_k)\mid \leq C \alpha(\mid t-k\mid)^{1/p}\leq C \alpha(M)^{1/p}$, since the dependence coefficient $\alpha$ is nonincreasing. On the other hand  $\alpha (\sigma(\epsilon_t),\sigma(\epsilon_k:k=a,b,c))\geq \alpha(\sigma(\epsilon_t),\sigma(\epsilon_k))$ for each $k\in\{a,b,c\}$, looking at the definition.

I know this question is quite specific (stochastic process), but I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: What is $a(M)$?

Comment: \begin{align}\alpha (n)&=\sup_{j\in\mathbb{Z}}\alpha(\sigma(\epsilon_t:1\leq t \leq j),\sigma(\epsilon_t:j+n\leq t))\\
&:= \sup_{j\in \mathbb{Z}}\alpha(\mathcal{F}_1^j,\mathcal{F}_{j+n}^\infty).
\end{align}   This relates to asymptotic independence.

Comment: And $\alpha(\sigma(X),\sigma(Y))=\sup_{B\in \sigma(X),C \in
\sigma(Y)}\mid P(B\cap C)-P(B)P(C)\mid$. These definitions are in the link I posted above.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity let $k=\min\{a,b,c\}>t$. Then $\epsilon_a\epsilon_b\epsilon_c\in \mathcal{F}_{k}^{\infty}$, and for $p>4$,
\begin{align}
|\operatorname{Cov}(\epsilon_t,\epsilon_a\epsilon_b\epsilon_c)|&\le 8\|\epsilon_t\|_p\|\epsilon_a\epsilon_b\epsilon_c\|_{p/3}\alpha(\mathcal{F}_1^{t},\mathcal{F}_{k}^{\infty})^{1-4/p} \\
&\le 8\sup_{t\ge 1}\|\epsilon_t\|_p^4\times \alpha(k-t)^{1-4/p},
\end{align}
where the first inequality uses Corollary A.2 in Hall & Heyde's Martingale Limit Theory and Applications (1980).

Comment: Wow. I would just post my answer now. And it takes exactly the index $k$ which is the minimum of $a,b,c$!! Exactly as you did. I will show bellow what I did (which uses some basic concepts). Thanks for your question. The inequality I use is the Davydov Inequality.

Comment: In the book I mentioned, the power $1/p$ is used for $\phi$-mixing coefficients.

Comment: I used Corollary 1.1 from D. Bosq's Nonparametric Statistics for Stochastic Process. If $\epsilon_t\in L^q$ and $\epsilon_a\epsilon_b\epsilon_c\in L^r$, my $p$ satisfies $1/q+1/r+1/p=1$.

Comment: Can you please read my answer below and see if everything is alright?

Answer (score 0):

Define $f(A,B)=\mid P(A\cap B)-P(A)P(B)\mid$ for measurable sets $A,B$ and let $k=\min(a,b,c)$. Note that 
\begin{align}
\alpha(\sigma(\epsilon_t),\sigma(\epsilon_l:l=a,b,c))&=\sup\{f(A,B):A\in\sigma(\epsilon_t),B\in\sigma(\epsilon_l:l=a,b,c)\}\\
&\leq\sup\{f(A,B):A\in\sigma(\epsilon_t),B\in\sigma(\epsilon_l:l\geq k)\}\\
&\in\{\sup\{f(A,B):A\in\sigma(\epsilon_j),B\in\sigma(\epsilon_l:l\geq j+\mid k-t\mid)\}:j\in\mathbb{Z}\}\\
&\subseteq\{\sup\{f(A,B):A\in\sigma(\epsilon_l:l\leq j),B\in\sigma(\epsilon_l:l\geq j+\mid k-t\mid)\}:j\in\mathbb{Z}\}\\
&:=\{\sup\{f(A,B):A\in\mathcal{F}_1^j,B\in\mathcal{F}_{j+\mid k-t\mid}^\infty\}:j\in\mathbb{Z}\}
\end{align}

By taking the supremum and keeping in mind that $\alpha(n)$ is nonincreasing, it follows that $\alpha(\sigma(\epsilon_t),\sigma(\epsilon_l:l=a,b,c))\leq \alpha(\mid k-t\mid)\leq \alpha(M)$. So, using the Davydov's inequality, it follows that 
$$\mid Cov(\epsilon_t,\epsilon_a\epsilon_b\epsilon_c)\mid\leq C \alpha (M)^{1/p},$$
assuming $\epsilon_t\in L^q, \epsilon_a\epsilon_b\epsilon_c\in L^r$ and $1/q+1/r=1-1/p$.